# Is there a way to return certain rows on Google Sheets that I have tagged?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I have a large list of books that I would like to tag and be able to filter out the row/book I am searching for without having to scroll through the entire sheet.

For example:

```
Book A        humor, non-ficton, hardback, modern, romance
Book B        auto-biography, fiction, paperback, romance 
Book C        paperback, fiction, young adult, romance
```

I currently have the titles and the tags in two different columns. When I use the filter function, it will only return tags with the exact string. So if I just filtered and looked for text containing "paperback," I would get both Book B and Book C, but if I were to do "paperback, fiction" only Book C would come up even though Book B is also paperback and fiction. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data is located in A1:B3, and the search term is entered in D3 & D4. In E1, put :

```
=FILTER(B:B,FIND(D4,B:B),FIND(D5,B:B))
```

Have a try and share if it work/understandable/not. ( :